# “free-as-in-speech” vs. "free-as-in-beer”

Tags: free-software, opensource-projects

What is the difference between "free-as-in-speech" and "free-as-in-beer"?

Comment: One thing I want to point out is that the "free as in speech" is often misused to refer the the GPL. While it is true that GPL software has nearly all the freedoms of public domain software (probably the most free software around) it is lacking the freedom to use the code in a proprietary codebase. GPL supporters say that this enhances the other freedoms because "no one could make it nonfree".

Comment: http://members.optushome.com.au/brendanscott/papers/four_fs_fallacies_brendanscott_020920.html

Comment: Renjith, would examples of the drastically different license terms for various software help you understand?

Comment: Visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis_versus_libre#.22Free_beer.22_vs_.22free_speech.22_distinction

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"Free as in free speech" vs "Free as in free beer" isn't a concept, it is an example of a concept. :-)

This example belongs to the GPL and is used to clarify the definition of "free" in the term "Free Software".

Free beer is gratis. It doesn't cost you anything. The term refers to the price of a product. This is not the intention of the word "free" in this context.

The intention is more like "free" in free speech, the liberty to say the things you want without getting censored.

Comment: could you explain from  the basic words , that is "free beer" and "free speech"? Why they taken beer and speech as the example?

Comment: There are no special reasons why this examples are used. The only one who can finally answer this question would be Richard Stallman, you can find his contact information there: http://stallman.org Could be an interesting answer *g*. For more about the phrase see: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FreeAsInBeer

Comment: Ok i will ask him and will post the reply from him asap.

Comment: Yes. I got the reply and it is posted here in this forum in [this link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3398/reply-from-richard-stallman-free-as-in-speech-and-free-as-in-beer) (EDIT: reposted as an answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3289/free-as-in-speech-vs-free-as-in-beer/3402#3402))

Comment: Doesn't free as in beer mean that you have some obligation (sales pitch or helping a buddy move) to the person originating the free beer?

Comment: @Renjith G: Those "beer" and "speech" are just examples that people (at least in the western world) get, because they reference commonly used expressions. People associate "free speech" with freedom or "freedom of speech", and "free beer" with taking benefit of something without paying.

Answer (score 26):

"free" is ambiguous in English, and FOSS people tend to mean the former when people misinterpret it as the latter, which is why the phrases came about

- **free as in speech** means freedom; in an open-source context, the license doesn't prevent you from fiddling with the code or making your own changes
- **free as in beer** means price; the software costs nothing

There was (is?) a lot of confusion when people said they support "free software" -- free (as in speech) software doesn't need to cost nothing, and costing nothing doesn't necessarily make software "free".

Comment: In "free as in speech means freedom", `s/freedom/liberty/` will make it more clear, I think.

Answer (score 22):

As I mentioned in the comments [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3289/free-as-in-speech-vs-free-as-in-beer/3291#3291), I e-mailed Mr. Richard Stallman about this. Here is his reply:

> From: Richard Stallman
>  Date: Fri,
>   Oct 22, 2010 at 9:12 AM
>  Subject:
>   Re: “free-as-in-speech” vs.
>   "free-as-in-beer”
>  To: RENJITH
>   G
>
> QN: I would like to know the exact
>   meaning of "free-as-in-speech" and
>   "free-as-in-beer"
>
> It is hard to give "exact" meanings
>   for philosophical concepts, so I am a
>   bit lost.
>
> The English word "free" has two
>   different meanings. Many other
>   languages have different words for
>   them. For instance, I think Hindi has
>   "mukt" for "free as in freedom" and
>   "muft" for "gratis, zero price'.
>
> QN: Also why this example words (the
>   words free-as-in-speech and
>   free-as-in-beer) are being used to
>   descibe the concept?
>
> Those are not the words I use. I use
>   "free as in 'free speech'" and "free
>   as in 'free beer'". Is that clearer?
>
> It seems you heard someone else
>   shorten the two phrases a little.
>
> --
>  Richard Stallman
>  President, Free Software Foundation
>  51
>   Franklin St
>  Boston MA 02110
>   USA
>  www.fsf.org, www.gnu.org

Comment: What is the exact meaning of "free as in "free speech" "? Is it possible to do free speech on any thing at anywhere ?

Comment: did you understand the concept "freedom of speech" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_speech ?

Comment: Renjith G: good questions, perhaps, it helps to analyze a bit. Beer can have repercussions such as hangover, while it is hard to see such repercussions from "free speech". If software is free-as-in-beer, perhaps, the term is used to point to the less free long-term perspective. It is hard to invent a general rule how to use the terms, better to break it into parts and ask when they are used as synonyms.

Comment: its got nothing to do with the hangover, its referring to the fact that the word free has two different meanings as in your free to do what you want, or here have a free beer.....

Comment: Great correspondence, thanks for sharing it!

Comment: BTW, he used it that way even here: https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/open-source-misses-the-point.en.html Possibly he thought the reader is capable of reading one paragraph as contextually one. Programmers often overestimate such capabilities of everyday humans.

Answer (score 2):

In Polish, those are very easily distinguishable, as we have completely different words for the two concepts:

- *wolny* represents the "free as in 'freedom'" (or 'free speech') concept
- *darmowy* represents the concept of "free as in 'free beer'" (something you do not need to pay for)

Comment: Hungarian the same ("szabad" vs. "ingyen"). Kisses Brother!

Answer (score 0):

Free-as-in-free-speech.

'Free' word used in the context of Free-speech. Free-speech itself is used very liberally as it's literal meaning could be quite misleading (esp to non-American). So to narrow it further take "Free-speech" as the one of the fundamental rights enjoyed by every US citizen as per US Constitution.

So the 'free' word in 'free software' stands that grand not only to the level of not paying for the software only.

I think everyone else has already accurately described - free as in beer concept. So I wouldn't repeat.